# Viewport shading bug 2.8

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

I can see the half of my viewport as u see it is no matter if I look through the cam or just so. Please help me out.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

*Render Region* is active in your project. You can clear the region by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or through *View > View Regions > Clear Render Region* in the menu.

In case you meant that part of your model is missing and not just the limited render view, then it's probably because of clipping start or end. Adjust the distances so that the entire model can be displayed.

[image]